# Absolute convergence of a sum involving sine function

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Explore absolute convergence of

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin\left(n+\frac1n\right)}{n^p}$$ for $1 \geq p > 0$.

No idea even where to start, I've tried cauchy's criterion, but got nothing useful.

Comment: Did you try the ratio test?

Comment: @5xum  yea, of course, but the limit is equal 1, right? So i get nothing from that test :(

Comment: @5xum if i didn't make a mistake, then I proved that the series itself converges. I guess the absolute series diverges, so i want to prove that the series converges conditionally

Comment: You may replace $\sin(n+1/n)$ with $\sin(n)$ without altering the absolute convergence, since the sine function is Lipschitz-continuous. After that, expand $\left|\sin(n)\right|$ as a Fourier cosine series and apply summation by parts. Such a series cannot be absolutely convergent since $|\sin(n)|$ is, on average, $\frac{2}{\pi}$ and if $p\in(0,1]$ the series $\sum_{n\geq 1}n^{-p}$ is divergent. On the other hand, the series is conditionally convergent by Dirichlet's test.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thank you very much for helping! But i don't know Fourier series yet :( SO here is how i solved him. First of all, yes,  we replace `sin(n+1/n)` with `sin(n)`. Then we have `|sin (n) | >= sin^2 (n) = (1-2cos (2n))/n`. We have `1/n^p` - diverges, and `cos(2n)/n^p` -converges by Dirichlets test.

Comment: Use the fact: $$\sin (n+\frac{1}{n}) = \sin n \cos \frac{1}{n} + \sin \frac{1}{n} \cos n.$$